# PostGIS: Unexpected results using ST_LineString and ST_Within

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-relationship

I am not sure if I get the functionality of `ST_LineSubstring` wrong, but in my understanding, I get some weird results using it - maybe somebody can explain this to me.

I am creating a segment from a line string using `ST_LineSubstring(lineGeom, start_point, end_point) as segment`. Applying `ST_Within(segment, lineGeom)` sometimes returns `true` and sometimes `false`, depending on the values for `start_point` and `end_point`.

How can this be? Shouldn't a section of a LineString **always** be within the LineString?

With these queries, I get unexpected results (`ST_Within` returning `false`)

```
select ST_WITHIN(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0, 0.007179297057500154), geom) FROM relations_road where r_id = 2;

select ST_WITHIN(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0, 0.1), geom) FROM relations_road where r_id = 2;

select ST_WITHIN(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0.1, 0.2), geom) FROM relations_road where r_id = 2;

select ST_WITHIN(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0.1, 0.5), geom) FROM relations_road where r_id = 2;
```

With these queries, I get expected results (`ST_Within` returning `true`)

```
select ST_WITHIN(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0, 0.9638126905064741), geom) FROM relations_road where r_id = 2;

select ST_WITHIN(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0.3989075612603054, 1), geom) FROM relations_road where r_id = 2;
```

Can this be due to inaccuracies in the formation of the segment?

Comment: Except for the comparably rare regularities in arbitrary vector space (e.g. grids), describing an infinitesimally small position vector (Point) on an infinitesimally thin direction vector (Linestring) is not possible with virtually (and eventually physically) bounded numeric coordinate precision. You will have to work around this limitation (snapping/gridding, tiny proximity thresholds), or just accept that you *know* that an extracted segment *is* part of the parent one.

Comment: You can make your queries to accept some tolerance by adding  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html into your SQL.

Comment: or add vertices to the parent line, then extract the segment between these points

Comment: You can also just add a small buffer (ST_Buffer) around your reference when you test the ST_Within

Comment: If you haven't read about floating point numbers, you should check that out.  Geometry processing in postgis is done with floats.  Floats are inherently inaccurate.  So you will end up with tiny differences in your line substring.  You need to snap you substring to your original line, or use st_snaptogrid on both geometries.  You may need to play with the grid size to get the tolerance right.